# Can we make twig remove whitespace when it's compiled, rather than when it's rendered?

Tags: php, templates, twig

Twig has the `{% spaceless %}` tag, which removes all the white space between HTML tags.

However, it does this with a preg_replace when you render the template.  Fine on small files, but if you have a large complex template there's a performance hit.

I feel like it should be possible to strip the whitespace out at compile time?

My compiled template is full of stuff like

```
        echo "    <h2>Heading</h2>
";
```

Where the template has included the following:

```
<section>
    <h2>Heading</h2>
</section>
```

What I want on the final rendered HTML is

```
<section><h2>Heading</h2></section>
```

Why couldn't twig (very simply) add a `trim` in when building the compiled template, to give us:

```
echo "<h2>Heading</h2>";
```

in the compiled template php code.

I get that there could still be whitespace in whatever data I populate the template with inside `{{ }}`, but I can control that from my PHP easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after much digging in the library trying to work out which files generate which bits of the output, I've finally found this "fix".

Change

```
->string($this->getAttribute('data'))
```

to

```
->string(trim(preg_replace('/>\s+</', '><', $this->getAttribute('data'))))
```

On line 30 of /lib/Twig/Node/Text.php.

Doing that correctly gives me a "spaceless" output, but without requiring the expensive template-render-time preg_replace call.

Will it cause problems?  Possibly in some use cases, maybe with a partial `<pre>` or `<textarea>` tag.  I can't see either of those being an issue for me though.

Any gotchas that I've not thought of?

Comment: Nice idea, you should propose this as an option on the Symfony or Twig issue queue.

Comment: Its nice, but the sad thing is, changing the inner of the library is not going to be working out when installed trough package managers. Since if there is a update, and you install it, the line above will just be removed again. At least if I understand library's/packages correctly.

Comment: Correct @Allart.  In theory I could submit it as a PR and they might merge it in, but in practice if they haven't already I can only assume they wouldn't want to - it's such a simple "fix", they must have their reasons for not doing so.  Some edge cases I've not considered, no doubt.

Comment: Yup, maybe because they have this already as well: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#whitespace-control. At least this did the job for me. Using `{{- -}}`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use trim function from Twig library

[trim - Documentation - Twig - The flexible, fast, and secure PHP template engine](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/trim.html)

Comment: You've misunderstood my question.

Answer (score -1):

The right tool for your needs if the spaces are in the template source is the whitespace control feature of Twig: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#whitespace-control

If the spaces are in a variable being displayed in the output, you should use the trim filter (or trim the variable before passing it to Twig, which will do the same anyway)

Comment: I'm not sure that that IS the right tool?  I'm talking about whitespace around barenaked bits of HTML in my twig template.  I've just edited the question to make this a bit clearer.